# One leetcode progra, dont understand statement

Tags: java, c++

‘.’ Matches any single character.
‘*’ Matches zero or more of the preceding element.
The matching should cover the entire input string (not partial).

The function prototype should be:
bool isMatch(const char *s, const char *p)

Some examples:

```
isMatch(“aa”,”a”) → false
isMatch(“aa”,”aa”) → true
isMatch(“aaa”,”aa”) → false
isMatch(“aa”, “a*”) → true
isMatch(“aa”, “.*”) → true
isMatch(“ab”, “.*”) → true
isMatch(“aab”, “c*a*b”) → true
```

for the last line

```
isMatch(“aab”, “c*a*b”) → true
```

is am not sure the `*` meaning,
i just thinking of `*` can match zero of many character like `*` can match any string(sequence of char), but it seems like not right

Answer (score 3):

> ‘*’ Matches zero or more of the preceding element.

`c*a*b` can be translated to

c - 0 times, a - 2 times and b - 1 time

Hence, equivalent to `aab`. The key thing to look at in the definition provided is -" ‘*’ Matches **zero or more** of the **preceding element**. "